# how to tripartition a convex polygon minimizing the maximal diameter of the three parts

Tags: math, geometry

I have a convex polygon P and I want to split it into three parts as follows: first a line l1 divides P into two parts P1 and P2, second another line l2 divides one of the two parts, say P1, into two parts P11 and P12. How can I do this to obtain the object that the maximal diameter of the three parts P11, P12, P2 is minimal? Or how can I obtain a approximate result?

First I want to use three circles to cover the polygon and minimize the maximal diameter of the circles, but I also do not kown how to obtain such circles yet. I have researched a lot on the problem, and cann't come up with a efficient algorithm. And most of the study is focus on how to partition points.

Are there any known algorithms to compute this? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: How big are your polygons? (so we know how much brute force is feasible)

Comment: how big? you mean the area or the vertexs? The area may be very large and we can assume the vertexs of the polygon is at most ten. How brute force works? Need to discretize the polygon first?

Comment: What do you mean by "discretize the polygon"?

Comment: Are you constraining the lines to go through vertices of the polygon, or can they cut through the middle of a side?

Comment: Thanks for all of you for the answer.  Discretize the polygon, I mean, splitting the polygon into as many as quadrangles with vertical and horizontal lines. Use a point in each quadrangle to denote the corresponding quadrangle and can thus can operate the points. This is not efficient and I am also not sure if it works.

Comment: Thank you arghbleargh: actually, the line can go through everywhere of the polygon. The constraints may obtain a approximate result. If I add them, I may need think up a convincing reason.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force will be enough.

Write a function that takes the convex polynomial as input, tries all diagonals in turn and splits the polygon in two parts. The diameter of both parts are easily found as being either the length of the splitting diagonal or the length of the longest diagonal of the initial polygon (if this longest diagonal belongs to the considered part).

You will use this function in a two step process, splitting the initial polygon, then splitting the second part.

As an optimization, you will keep a trace of the shortest maximum diameter obtained so far; when you will try a new split, there will be no point trying a first split with a longer diagonal than that current minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. According to your method, the polygon will always be cut by the diagonals. But I think most of the time, the optimal cut may be the lines across two edges other than exactly cross the vertexes. Think about a convex quadrangle. First a diagnal splits it into two triangles and second the triangle cannot be split by diagonal. Did I misunderstand your thought?

Comment: Yep, I underestimated the fact that splits can be across edges. Then this problem is too hard for me.